# How to format currency column in streamlit for dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I have the following piece of code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

cashflow = pd.DataFrame(data=[
  (2023, 10000),
  (2022, 95000),
  (2021, 90000),
  (2020, 80000),
], columns=['year', 'cashflow'])

st.dataframe(
   data=cashflow,
   column_config={
     'year': st.column_config.NumberColumn(format='%d'),
     'cashflow': st.column_config.NumberColumn(label='cashflow', format='$%.0f'),
   }
)
```

But, this outputs the `cashflow` column as `$95000` but I want it output `$95,000`

Comment: try `format='$%,.0f'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: '$%,.0f' does not work with Streamlit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer use the [`Styler`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) instead of the `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

cashflow = pd.DataFrame(data=[
  (2023, 10000),
  (2022, 95000),
  (2021, 90000),
  (2020, 80000),
], columns=['year', 'cashflow'])

st.dataframe(
   data=cashflow.style.format({'cashflow': '${:,}'}),  # <- HERE
)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to play around with the format specifier:

```
In [241]: cashflow.cashflow.apply(lambda n: "$ " + format(n, ',.02f'))
Out[241]:
0    $ 10,000.00
1    $ 95,000.00
2    $ 90,000.00
3    $ 80,000.00
```